# Is it possible to have same property with two different names in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have a property in a class like:

```
public int ProductID {get;set;}
```

Is it possible in .NET to make some 'alias' for this property like to **give it another name** like '`Product_Id`'?

So later I can set this property by using:

```
obj.ProductID = 555;
```

and

```
obj.Product_Id = 666;
```

Comment: Why not make a field `private int productID;`, and two properties, both with the same body of `{ get { return productID; } set { productID = value; } }`? Or if you have some existing code that uses `Product_Id` or something, you can just do a find and replace to fix it.

Comment: just wondering why is this ever needed

Comment: @nawfal I am asking myself the same question... what am I missing that I can't see how this is usefull in anyway.

Comment: @nawfal, just because you don't see a use-case doesn't mean you should *ever* assume there isn't one. This is one of the things I hate about C# is in the language specification there are so many times "no one needs this" and we have to bend over backwards to make things work.

Comment: @Sebastien If it pleases you, one example (that made me google this) I am making a hardware interface to that provides bitmasks to individual pins on a GPIO port. The port is multipurpose (GPIO) so it can send 8 bits as a byte in parallel or be used as a one bit signal. Thus it makes sense to be able to call them either `PinA` or `Bit0` in my `Port8Pin` class (internally using a `BitArray`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure:

```
public int Product_Id { get { return ProductID; } set { ProductID = value; } }
```

Answer (score 8):

```
private int _prodId;

public int ProductID { get { return _prodId; } set { _prodId = value; } }
public int Product_ID { get { return _prodId; } set { _prodId = value; } }
```

both `ProductID` and `Product_ID` relate to the same member.

Answer (score 6):

Not an alias, but you can just add another property that redirects to that property.

```
public int ProductID {get;set;}
public int Product_ID
{
    get { return ProductID; }
    set { ProductID = value;
}
```